# How can I convert PDF to doc without microsoft.office.interop?

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, ms-office, openoffice.org, doc

I need to convert PDF files into .doc files using C#. The computer has no file system though it doesn't have Office installed. Any good ideas how I can approach this? I did some research and most of people use the interop services.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "the computer has no file system" because the statement does not make sense.  Honestly the best approach is the office interop.

Comment: No windows operating system installed maybe?

Comment: Well, the computer pretty much just strems... Also, I need to convert PDF to PNG and DOC to PNG... I've no idea how to do this without interop

Comment: why don't you buy a tool to do this. If you aren't prepared to do that and want to write it yourself then the question is way too broad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to understand that PDF is not really implemented as a single document format.

If your PDF docs are created by rendering text to a PDF file, then direct PDF conversion is not only possible, but can be very good (reliable).

If the source of your PDF is either a scanner or fax (essentially a scanner...) then what you have is a document with an "picture" of text. This scenario is more difficult to deal with. If you open up the markup for this there is no 'text' to be converted. In this situation you have to deal with some manner of OCR (optical character recognition) which is less reliable due to a variety of issues.

If you have the option of intercepting the data before it is rendered to PDF (say like in SSRS or Crystal) then it would be better for you to bypass the PDF stage and move your data to a Word document.

If you are constrained to receiving faxes and then needing to interpret their content, prepare for OCR hell. It has been a while since I was there, so I hope that it has gotten better.

Even with out office installed on your machine, you have access (with Visual Studios) to the Office developer toolkit which will allow you build documents to be distributed in the Word formats.(.doc/.docx).

Answer (score 0):

An option/idea may be to convert the PDF to Html, which can be opened in Word?

Answer (score 0):

use aspose pdf kit to conver pdf to text and then text to doc using filestream or aspose doc